# How to handle an exception that happens in a future in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm writing a controller method in play framework that calls a function that returns a Future that may also throw an Exception. I'm having trouble figuring out how to catch and handle that Exception.

Here's what I tried:

```
  def openIDCallback = Action { implicit request =>
    Async (
      Try(OpenID.verifiedId) match {
        case Failure(thrown) => {
          PurePromise(Ok("failed: " + thrown))
        }
        case Success(successResult) => {
          successResult.map( userInfo => {
            Ok(userInfo.id + "\n" + userInfo.attributes)
          })
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

OpenID.verifiedId is the function from Play's OpenId api that returns Future[UserInfo]. Here's the source of that function:

```
def verifiedId(queryString: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Future[UserInfo] = {
    (queryString.get("openid.mode").flatMap(_.headOption),
      queryString.get("openid.claimed_id").flatMap(_.headOption)) match { // The Claimed Identifier. "openid.claimed_id" and "openid.identity" SHALL be either both present or both absent.
      case (Some("id_res"), Some(id)) => {
        // MUST perform discovery on the claimedId to resolve the op_endpoint.
        val server: Future[OpenIDServer] = discovery.discoverServer(id)
        server.flatMap(directVerification(queryString))(internalContext)
      }
      case (Some("cancel"), _) => PurePromise(throw Errors.AUTH_CANCEL)
      case _ => PurePromise(throw Errors.BAD_RESPONSE)
    }
  }
```

As shown above, function can return PurePromise(throw Errors.AUTH_CANCEL) and PurePromise(throw Errors.BAD_RESPONSE). My attempt at solution handles successes correctly, but on exceptions I get:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[AUTH_CANCEL$: null]]
```

My question is how do I catch and handle these exceptions in my controller method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `recover` method of `Future` instead of `Try` like this:

```
Async (
  OpenID.verifiedId.
    map{userInfo => Ok(userInfo.id + "\n" + userInfo.attributes)}.
    recover{ case thrown => Ok("failed: " + thrown) }
)
```

`Try` can help you in case `verifiedId` throws an exception instead of returning `Future`. In your case `verifiedId` successfully returns `Future` (even if there will be an exception in this `Future`).

Comment: Thanks - I did look into recover but didn't understand the concept of PartialFunction. Your example worked and clarified the concept for me.

Comment: @KresimirNesek: `PartialFunction` (and pattern matching) is one of the most important and useful tool in scala. See `9. Pattern matching` section in [Scala tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info).